# How to upload file in swagger in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, swagger-ui

I want to upload a file within Swagger UI of my project, the controller method should accept an object which contains a Long and a Multipart file, how should I do that?

This is request object:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class BankFileUploadRequest {

    @NotNull(message = "{validation.bankFileRequestModel.bankAccountId.null}")
    private final Long bankAccountId;
    @NotNull(message = "{validation.bankFileRequestModel.file.null}")
    private final MultipartFile file;

}
```

and besides that I have a custom Spring validator which validates BankFileUploadRequest, and I want to have a controller method as:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void uploadFile(@Validated BankFileUploadRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

what kind of annotations should I add to request argument, and how to have file upload support in swagger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `@ModelAttribute` to the parameter solved the issue, now both Swagger supports the file upload, and it works, so the signature of controller method is:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void uploadFile(@ModelAttribute("request") @Validated BankFileUploadRequest request) {
    ....
}
```